# Microsoft Access SQL - Select Most Recent "Version" of Record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on a select query that selects the list of approvers for a given record based on the foreign key `EFTRecIDNum`. The list of approvers are stored in table `tblApprover`, with relevant fields `EFTRecIDNum`, `Approver`, `ApprovalTime`, and `ApproverAction`. The challenge is that I need all records for a given `EFTRecIDNum` expect where an approver has done the same action more then once (which does have a business purpose). In that case I would need to select the newest record. My data looks like this:

`+------+-------------+----------+--------------+----------------+
|  ID  | EFTRecIDNum | Approver | ApprovalTime | ApproverAction |
+------+-------------+----------+--------------+----------------+
|  503 |         111 | Person A | 09-Jun-16    | Reviewed       |
|  865 |         111 | Person B | 10-Jun-16    | Reviewed       |
| 1517 |         111 | Person C | 11-Jun-16    | Reviewed       |
| 1610 |         111 | Person C | 12-Jun-16    | Reviewed       |
| 1743 |         111 | Person D | 13-Jun-16    | Approved       |
| 1744 |         111 | Person C | 14-Jun-16    | Approved       |
+------+-------------+----------+--------------+----------------+`

Where I need to select everything but ID number 1517.

I've tried a few different things with joins and subselects but always end up only selecting the most recent reviewer/approver.

```
SELECT
    a.EFTRecIDNum,
    a.Approver, 
    a.ApprovalTime, 
    a.ApproverAction
FROM tblApprover a INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT ApproverAction, MAX(ApprovalTime) as sTime
      FROM tblApprover GROUP BY ApproverAction) b 
on a.ApproverAction=b.ApproverAction and a.ApprovalTime = b.sTime
```

Please let me know if there is anything I can add or clarify.

EDIT: Added another line of data to clarify.

Comment: It seems to me that the newer record is `1610`, not `1517`.

Comment: Why are you joining on just approverAction instead of EFTREcIDNum with approval Time and approver?  `(select EFTRecIDNum, Approver, ApproverAction max(approvalTime) sTime from tblApprover GROUP BY EFTRecIDNum, Approver, ApproverAction) b ON ...`

Comment: You're right at @TimBiegeleisen, I updated

Comment: So if ID 1744 for EFTRecIDNum 111 for Person C with approval time 14-Jun-16 with action of Approved existed as well you'd see two records for person C ID 1610 and 1744 right?  I'm trying to clarify:  `I need all records for a given EFTRecIDNum expect where an approver has done the same action more then once` as that example isn't in sample data.

Comment: @xQbert that's right yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me your join is incomplete you need the other fields...

First we generate a set of records with the highest ID for a ApproverAction, approver and EFTRecIDNum (B).  We then join this base set to our entire set (A)  on the relevant fields.  If time can be identical we can't use time as the max key as this would cause duplication the results, and ID would have to be used; if we can assume you want the max ID (and now I'm assuming ID is unique)

```
SELECT
    a.EFTRecIDNum,
    a.Approver, 
    a.ApprovalTime, 
    a.ApproverAction
FROM tblApprover a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ApproverAction, MAX(ApprovalTime) as sTime, Approver, EFTRecIDNum
            FROM tblApprover 
            GROUP BY ApproverAction, Approver, EFTRecIDNum) b 
 on a.ApproverAction = b.ApproverAction 
and a.ApprovalTime = b.sTime
and a.approver = b.approver
and a.eftrecIDNum = b.EFTRecIDNum
```

Maybe time has duplicates so we may need to key off ID?

```
SELECT
    a.EFTRecIDNum,
    a.Approver, 
    a.ApprovalTime, 
    a.ApproverAction
FROM tblApprover a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ApproverAction, MAX(ID) as mID, Approver, EFTRecIDNum
            FROM tblApprover 
            GROUP BY ApproverAction, Approver, EFTRecIDNum) b 
 on a.ApproverAction = b.ApproverAction 
and a.ID = b.mid
and a.approver = b.approver
and a.eftrecIDNum = b.EFTRecIDNum
```

The only difference between the two queries is what we use to define a "UNIQUE" record in terms of (approver, ApprovalAction, and EFTRecIDNum) If ApprovalTime can be duplicated for a given "Unique" then Approvaltime not unique enough.

Usually ID's are UNIQUE and in Access sequential (if auto number) so I assumed we could key off it as a unique value  Since you only wanted 1 record per approveraction, approver, and EFTRecIDNum, we simply had the system pick the one with the highest ID.  Then by joining this subset back to the all of the data, we were able to eliminate all but the highest ID per combination of EFTRecIDNum, Approver, and ApproverAction.  This allowed us to find the one with the highest time. (and potentially other data if needed)

Comment: This is definitely close to what I'm trying to do, when I test though I still get 2 records with the same reviewer/approver doing the same action.

Comment: Do they have the same approval time?  if so instead of keying off of time can we key off of the largest ID and assume the largest ID would be the most recent?  if time is different can you give me an example of a record that is duplicating?  the first should work, and the 2nd should if we can assume the highest ID can be kept.  (assuming ID is an autonum)

Comment: We can assume that a newer time will have a higher ID. I added another line of data to show that Person C should be listed twice if they both reviewed and approved.

Comment: @jcarroll then the 2nd query should work as it's based on maxID and eliminates the change of a duplicate time.

Comment: The second one works exactly as I need, thank you so much. I'm going to go through your solution to try and understand it.

Comment: The reason why you get 2 records w/ the same revier/approver was due to the fact that you have an Approver with the same EFTRecIDNum  with the same ApproverAction AND with the same Approvertime.  If they had different times, the 1st solution would have worked.  Since ApproverTime wasn't enough to distinguish we needed a different value to key off of (the ID made sense to me) So  We generated a set of data having just the max ID, of a unique person, approvalAction, and EFTRecIDNum..  This eliminated the duplicate time record.  then by joining back to the total set we get all the needed data.